# how to get a combination name using Eval()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm wondering how to get a combination name like "test1" by using `<%# Eval("id") %>`

I want to name a div by the id field from a datatable, I can get the id in frontend by using `<%# Eval("id") %>`, I want the div name to be something like test1, test2.

Is this right?

```
<div id="<%# test+Eval("id") %>"></div>
```

This code is supposed to write in frontend page of an asp.net website project.

Comment: I thought that JavaScript was only available in classic ASP, not ASP.NET?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: The JavaScript `eval` function doesn't have a capital `E`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="test<%=Eval("id")%>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the div is in a databound control use:

```
 <div id='<%# "test"+Eval("id") %>'></div>
```

Eval() method works only in a databound control

**Single-Value Databinding**
or if the id is a protected/public variable

```
 <div id="<%# "test"+id %>"></div>
```

or even call your own method (protected/public)

```
<div id= "<%# "test"+Counter() %>"></div>
```

Then in the page load event call this method

```
 DataBind()
```